# Что значит сайт на песке,и можно ли выгрузить как-нибудь логи

Tags: php

Всем привет.Нужны логи сайта,обычно их  можно получить непосредственно на хостинге,но мне сказали сайт на "песке"(что это и как?),поэтому логи никак не выгрузить.
так ли это или можно как то выгрузить?Нужно понять когда приходит бот и как он приходит

Comment: Вам случайно не «випееске» сказали? Первую букву не потеряли?

Comment: Ахахаха, @andreymal, не за что бы не догадался. ТС, а может сайт на плеске? Панель такая

Answer (score 1):

Скорее речь про "песочницу" (sandbox). Ваш сайт работает в изолированном от остальных окружении. Это не мешает, в принципе, выгрузке логов, но, вероятно, логи в данной настройке окружения просто не предусмотрены.

В принципе, если логи действительно недоступны, можно попробовать самостоятельно дописать логгирование в файл и вывод этих логов на отдельной странице, но всё сильно зависит от используемого движка. Может оказаться что для этого придётся вносить изменения во множестве мест.